# A left outer join on table that may or may not exist - can i avoid job failure?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm looking to do a join like

```
select 
  a.*,
  b.info 
from 
  [table_a] a
left outer join
  [table_b_20160510] b
on
  a.id=b.id
```

[table_b_yyyymmdd] is a log table that may or may not exist and i can't know in advance.

Is there a way to formulate this query such that it wont fail if an individual log table for a particular date does not happen to exist?

I know i can do a table date range function but it could even end up that a reasonable range of days might be missing logs (primarily historical from before we started capturing them).

My solution is to make a big table_b that has everything and a log date then subselect out the date range of interest so if that returns 0 rows then no problem. It's just that my big table_b of all the logs will get crazy big before long so this approach seems a bit inefficient.

I also tried table_query() here to see if maybe that would fail gracefully but it throws an error (which of course makes sense).

```
select 
  * 
from 
  (select 'test' as id) a
left outer join 
  (select * from TABLE_QUERY(misc,'table_id CONTAINS "FOO_THIS_TABLE_DOES_NOT_EXIST"')) b
on 
  a.id=b.id
```

Comment: Perhaps using table_query() might be an option here? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference?hl=en#tablewildcardfunctions

Comment: Anyone know a way to do this in standard sql - is there something equivalent to TABLE_QUERY()?

Comment: actually i think a where condition on _TABLE_SUFFIX would do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I could do 
Assume below is your `table_b_20160510`:

```
SELECT * FROM temp.table_b_20160510

Row id  info     
1   1   abc  
2   2   xyz
```

I would create empty table with exactly same schema and zero rows - `table_b_empty`

```
SELECT * FROM temp.table_b_empty

Row id  info     
Query returned zero records.
```

So, now consider below query:

```
SELECT a.*, b.info 
FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1 AS id), (SELECT 2 AS id), (SELECT 3 AS id)) a
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT * FROM TABLE_QUERY
    (temp, 'table_id = "table_b_20160510" OR table_id = "table_b_empty"')
  ) b
ON a.id=b.id
```

Table - table_b_20160510 - exists, so result is:

```
Row a_id    b_info   
1   1       abc  
2   2       xyz  
3   3       null
```

Now, try with table_b_20160511 (assuming it does not exist)

```
SELECT a.*, b.info 
FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1 AS id), (SELECT 2 AS id), (SELECT 3 AS id)) a
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT * FROM TABLE_QUERY
    (temp, 'table_id = "table_b_20160511" OR table_id = "table_b_empty"')
  ) b
ON a.id=b.id
```

No failure and result is:

```
Row a_id    b_info   
1   1   null     
2   2   null     
3   3   null
```

Hope you can adopt this idea to your particular case

Comment: Does anyone know if there is an equivalent of this using standard sql?